# How to fix error 1305 where JSON_EXTRACT function does not exist in sql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have Json data in one of my columns (`student_data`) from table named `data`.
The json data is as such:

```json
[{"student_id":"1001","student_name":"patroclus","student_course":"medicine"},
 {"student_id":"1002","student_name":"achilles","student_course":"acrhery"}]
```

I want to extract the student_name from this data, but I couldn't do it. I'm using phpmyadmin to access my database.

I tried using the following query:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`student_data`, '$.student_name') AS student_name FROM `data`;
```

The error from MySQL says:

> #1305 - FUNCTION data.JSON_EXTRACT does not exist

Comment: What's your MySQL version? Those functions were only introduced in 5.7

Comment: mine is 5.6.51. Is there any alternative for my version?

Comment: Sadly no. That version is no longer in support and you really should upgrade, preferably to version 8 as 5.7 will end support later this year.